# SQL data table and lookup table in query

Tags: sql, linq, datatable, lookup

I have a lookup table like

```
CategoryId          Name
1                    Blue
2                    Red
3                    Orange
```

and I have a data table like

```
Id        CategoryId1       CategoryId2
1           2                1
2           1                3
```

I would like to get following query result

```
Id         Category1        Category2
1            Red               Blue
2            Blue              Orange
```

How to do that?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT [Id]
      ,ISNULL(Desc1.Name,'')
      ,ISNULL(Desc2.Name,'')
FROM table2
LEFT OUTER JOIN table1 Desc1 on Desc1.CategoryID= table2.CategoryId1
LEFT OUTER JOIN table1 Desc2 on Desc2.CategoryID = table2.CategoryId2
```

Comment: Although this code might answer the question, one should always add an explanation why/how the problem is solved

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that `CategoryId1` and `CategoryId2` cannot be null's, simple `inner join` should be sufficient.

```
SELECT t1_1.Id as Id, t1_1.Name as Category1, t1_2 as Category2
  FROM table2 t2
  INNER JOIN table1 t1_1 on t1_1.CategoryId = t2.CategoryId1
  INNER JOIN table1 t1_2 on t1_2.CategoryId = t2.CategoryId2
```